# Registration to Rockstar gaming social club

Tags: max-payne-3, rockstar-games-social-club

Is it possible to play Max Payne 3 without registering to Rockstar's social club?
Do I have to login to it every time I play?

Comment: From previous experience with the social club (especially in LA Noire) I can say that no, you don't have to, although there are usually benefits for doing so (in LA:N, a lot of hidden items were tracked there).  I did not have to log in each time, I was logged in automatically when the game started.

Comment: Agreed, you don't "need" to log into the social club for GTA4 either - I would assume 'No but some functionality may be restricted'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some previous games you need to be logged in to the Rockstar Social Club if you want to be able to play, even single player. (This is for the PC steam version at least)